# ionic app + Angular ng-switch-when Not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change, ng-switch

I have a fully working Ionic app where I've added angular switches to manipulate certain divs in the view.

The problem occurs on the ion-footer-bar. It always defaults to facebook (index 0) and just completely ignores the instagram `ng-switch-when`.
In the chrome developer I can clearly see the ng-switch in action, yet the erroneous behavior is persistent, no matter what I do.

I've tried all different kind of changes to no avail, I'm starting to think it has to do with how Ionic builds it's **ion-content** &  **ion-footer-bar** elements (?)

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
    <select ng-model="selectedNetwork" ng-change="setSelected(selectedNetwork.id)" data-ng-options="availableNetwork as availableNetwork.label for availableNetwork in availableNetworksForSelect track by availableNetwork.id">
    </select>

    //*******Please note that These two divs work perfectly*********
    <div ng-switch = "selectedNetwork.id" class="">
        <div ng-switch-when = "facebook" class="" >
            <span>I am Facebook</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "instagram" class="">
            <span>I am instagram</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar ng-switch = "selectedNetwork.id">
    <div ng-switch-when = "facebook" class="" >
        <span>I am Facebook</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when = "instagram" class="">
        <span>I am instagram</span>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

**This is the controller**

```
$scope.availableNetworksForSelect = [{
                                id: 'facebook',
                                label: 'This is Facebook'
                            }, {
                                id: 'instagram',
                                label: 'This is instagram'
                            }];

$scope.selectedNetwork = $scope.availableNetworksForSelect[0];
```

EDIT: per request, here is `setSelected();`

```
$scope.setSelected = function (network) {
    console.log('setSelected', network)
    $scope.selectedTab = network;
    $scope.translationData = {
        network: network.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + network.substring(1)
    };
    var currentTabNetworkTerms;
    if (!_.isUndefined($scope.baba.networks)) {
        currentTabNetworkTerms = _.find($scope.baba.networks, {code: network}).actions;
        $scope.currentTabNetworkActions = _.sortBy(currentTabNetworkTerms, function (term) {
            if (term.name == "post") {
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is probably bound to the `ion-content` directive, so the `ion-footer-bar` falls outside of its scope

Comment: @devqon - what would be best practice to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

don't use `ng-switch` as attribute of `ion-footer-bar` 
updated code is

```
<ion-footer-bar> 
    <ng-switch on="selectedNetwork.id">
        <div ng-switch-when = "facebook" class="" >
            <span>I am Facebook</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "instagram" class="">
            <span>I am instagram</span>
        </div>
    </ng-switch>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: The "on" addition isn't neccessary, since i've added it and I get the same results, `<ion-content>` switch works, whereas the switch at `<ion-footer-bar>` doesn't work, just like before adding "on"

Comment: I already added the code for `ion-footer-bar` also, please check - @DudeOfLayers

Comment: -what code did you add? I don't follow re your last comment, please explain.

Comment: I have moved `ng-switch` from `ion-footer-bar` to its children dom

Comment: `<ng-switch on="selectedNetwork.id">` <= this is possible to write like this? I beleive it's supposed to be a div attribute

Comment: sure, you can use `ng-switch` as element

Comment: I've done that, and nope it's still shows my default choice (instagram) and doesnt switch to FB, while the top ng-switch (ion-content) works perfectly.

Comment: post your `setSelected` function also

Comment: I've added `setSelected();` to the question.

Comment: I don't think that `setSelected();` has anything to do with this, but I would be happy to be taught something new.

Comment: If there was a way to simply transfer my select option choice to the io-footer div could be a quick way out, can you add to your answer that kind of approach? \

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137444/discussion-between-dudeoflayers-and-gaurav).